# send method is always returning 0

Tags: php, email, symfony, smtp, swiftmailer

I'm using swift_mailer to handle sending emails and I'm having a problem which is emails are not sent, and the return value of the `send` method is always equal to zero.

<kbd>app/config/config.yml</kbd>

```
swiftmailer:
   transport: smtp
   host:      <host>  # of the company
   username:  <username> # of the company
   password:  <password> # of the company
   port: 25
```

<kbd>app/config/config_test.yml</kbd>

```
swiftmailer:
    disable_delivery: true
    # disable_delivery: ~ # tried with this too
```

<kbd>Controller</kbd>

```
$mailer = $this->get('mailer');
$message = $mailer->createMessage()
    ->setSubject('You have Completed Registration!')
    ->setFrom('send@example.com')
    ->setTo('valid_email@Iswear.fr')
    ->setBody(
        'hello world!!',
        'text/plain'
    )

var_dump($mailer->send($message, $failed), $failed); exit;
```

Output:

```
int(0)
array(0) {
}
```

I know that send returns the number of persons the email has been sent to. Why the email is never sent? 
Given that I'm sure of the only email address I'm trying to send to.

Update1:

I'd like to know how to debug this much further.

Comment: in which environnement are you ? disable_delivery does not send any email , (use for test or dev ...)

Comment: swiftmailer:
    disable_delivery: true in dev environment => no emails will ever be sent in dev

Comment: try with disable_delivery: false

Comment: @pcm this is expected, but the send méthod should return 1, shouldn't it?

Comment: not necessarily. If you want to achieve a test environment, disable_delivery isn't the answer.

Comment: I will post an answer now.

Comment: @pcm `disable_delivery: false` works and `disable_delivery: ~` doesn't work :(, I thought it was the same thing. Anyways, it works now. thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75833/discussion-between-pcm-and-smarber).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to achieve a test environment mailer, do not use disable_delivery.
That completely disables swiftmailer's send.
Use

```
# app/config/config_dev.yml
swiftmailer:
      disable_delivery: false
      delivery_address: dev@example.com # some test or development email account
```

Comment: actually this disable_delivery statement should be set to false as you said: `disable_delivery: false`, please update your answer so that I can mark it as solved my problem

Comment: Edited. If you need any help further, don't hesitate to ask :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have an error in your config. Try the logger for debug output:
http://swiftmailer.org/docs/plugins.html#logger-plugin